# How can you style the Drop-Target-Indicator of WPF-Datagrid while sorting?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

If you reoder the columns of a Datagrid by dragging a ColumnHeader you get an indicator that shows you where the column will be placed. How can you style this indicator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the Aero theme has for the indicator. I believe you are looking to style this.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static DataGridColumnHeader.ColumnHeaderDropSeparatorStyleKey}" TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF000080" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here is the link to the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.datagridcolumnheader.columnheaderdropseparatorstylekey.aspx)

**Edit:**
I think there is a simpler way for styling dragging and dropping header controls using **DragIndicatorStyle** and **DropLocationIndicatorStyle** properties of DataGrid. I tested the following code and datagrid picked up the style.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DragHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="DropHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid DragIndicatorStyle="{StaticResource DragHeaderStyle}" 
          DropLocationIndicatorStyle="{StaticResource DropHeaderStyle}"
          ...>
</DataGrid>
```

See if you can override the Control Template to suit your need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seemed like the solution to my problem. But unfortunately it didn't work. I also couldn't find any "official examples/templates" on the net that address this issue. Where can I find the Aero Theme sources?

Comment: Download it from http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpfsamples&DownloadId=7812 . If you still can't get it to work, I will try at my end.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The themes are really helpful! I copied the Styles for both "DataGridColumnHeader.ColumnFloatingHeaderStyleKey" and "DataGridColumnHeader.ColumnHeaderDropSeparatorStyleKey" into my MergedDictionary to override the defaults with no luck. At first I thought the main reason for that is that I'm using a custom DataGrid which extends from the default one. But I'v also tried to style a default DataGrid and event to put the Styles directly into App.xaml without any changes. :-(

Comment: I am not very sure why it not working for your case, but there is a simpler way. See the EDIT of my answer for the code.

Comment: Awesome! It worked like a charm and it's cleaner solution! Thanks so much for your patience.